# How to get the result based on the condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider Issue Details table has Overall_Issues_ID and Fixed_Issues_ID Column. I need to get the result based on certain condition as below.

Condition: if the Overall_Issues_ID Value exists in any one of the Fixed_Issues_ID Column, then those ID should be consider as Fixed or else it is considered as Not Fixed.

[image]

I am using Oracle Version 10 G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the ID in a subquery:

```
select 
  overall_issues_id as id,
  case when overall_issues_id in (select fixed_issues_id from issue_details fixed) 
    then 'Fixed' else 'Not Fixed' end as fixed
from issue_details;
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the same table twice with different alias names

```
select i1.overall_issues_id, 
       case when i2.overall_issues_id is not null 
            then 'fixed'
            else 'not fixed'
       end as is_fixed
from issues_details i1
left join issues_details i2 on i2.fixed_issues_id = i1.overall_issues_id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6b29/1)

Comment: Right idea, incorrect implementation. With everything else as you defined and aliased it, the join should be a right join, and the test should be on i2.fixed_issues_id, not on i2.overall_issues_id. You may use the cte in my answer for testing.

Comment: I switched the column names in the join by mistake. Corrected it now and added a fiddle. Thanks for the hint.